# _____ Cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I think I almost have it.
 My PhraseGameController Class is not finding "isHidden"

My error messages are "isHidden cannot be resolved to a variable"
"letter cannot be resolved to a variable"
"The method isHidden() is undefined for the type PhraseGameController
(I will comment my problem areas)

● Go through each Letter in the currentPhrase

○ Check to see if it is hidden

○ If it is, set isWon to false.  Use break to exit the loop.

● Return isWon

```
   package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame;
import edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PhraseGameController { 

    private Phrase currentPhrase; 
    private ArrayList<Character> guessed; 
    private ArrayList<Player> players; 
    boolean isRoundWon;Letter letter;

    PhraseGameController Player = new PhraseGameController();


    public void addPlayer(String name) {
        Player player= new Player(name);
        players.add(player);

    }
public boolean isRoundWon(boolean isWon) {
isWon = true;
letter=new Letter();
    if(letter.isHidden() = true) {   ///<<<< Problem area, isHidden
        isWon = false;
        break;
    } else if { (letter.isHidden() = false);  ///<<<< Problem area, isHidden
    isWon = true;   
    return isWon;
    break;
    }

    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }                           









    public boolean doPlayerGuess(Character play) {

        Character guess = Character.toUpperCase(play);
        if(guessed.contains(play)){
            throw new IllegalStateException("the letter was already guessed");
    } else if (!String.valueOf(play).matches("[A-Z]")) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("the guess should be a letter from A­Z");
    }

    guessed.add(guess); 
    return currentPhrase.guessLetter(guess);

    }







    public PhraseGameController(){
    currentPhrase = new Phrase("This is only a test");
    guessed = new ArrayList<Character>();       
    }



     public Phrase getCurrentPhrase() {  
        return currentPhrase;
    }
    public void setCurrentPhrase(Phrase currentPhrase) {
        this.currentPhrase = currentPhrase;
    }

    public void setGuessedLetters(ArrayList<Character> guessed) {
        this.guessed = guessed;
    }
    public ArrayList<Character> getGuessedLetters() { 
        return guessed;
    }
}
```

> and

```
package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model;

public class Letter {
public char letter;

public boolean isHidden;

public char getLetter() {
    return letter;
}
public boolean isHidden() {
    return isHidden;
}

public void unhide() {
    isHidden = false;

}
public Letter(char letter) {
    this.letter = letter;
    if (String.valueOf(letter).matches("[A-Z]")) {
        isHidden = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Look at all those related questions though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this Letter letter=new Letter(); and after that  letter.isHidden()

```
package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame;
import edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PhraseGameController { 

    private Phrase currentPhrase; 
    private ArrayList<Character> guessed; 
    private ArrayList<Player> players; 
    boolean isRoundWon;Letter letter;

    PhraseGameController Player = new PhraseGameController();


    public void addPlayer(String name) {
        Player player= new Player(name);
        players.add(player);

    }
public boolean isRoundWon(boolean isWon) {
isWon = true;letter=new Letter();
    if(letter.isHidden() = true) {   ///<<<< Problem area, isHidden
        isWon = false;
        break;
    } else if { (letter.isHidden() = false)  ///<<<< Problem area, isHidden
    isWon = true;   
    return isWon;
    break;
    }

    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }
```

Comment: The constructor Letter() is Undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing methods wrong.

`isHidden.letter` should be `letter.isHidden()`

Also don't both putter `= true`. Firstly, boolean expressions will be evaluated anyway so you don't need to compare it to anything. Secondly, you should be using == or .equals() to compare two values, = is strictly for assignments

Comment: That helps but it still says I need to create a local variable for letter.   Its public, I guess maybe I don't understand why PhraseGameController class isin't seeing it in the Letter Class.

Comment: Yeah you have a class for Letter but you actually need to make the object, see JqueryLearner's reply that should help.

Answer (score 0):

IsHidden is not defined as a variable. It is a method. You should it call as .isHidden().